# ElasticSearch - Increase distance if no results

Tags: elasticsearch

Would it be possible to create query that would increase the `distance` field when no results are found?

Here's an example of a query that will return whether there's a match or not:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "100km",
                    "location": {
                        "lat": 40,
                        "lon": -7
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I would like that Elasticsearch could keep looking until at least 1  item is found.

I could increase the value programmatically and make a new query with `"distance": "200km"` and so on... until I find something, but I would like to make a query that would do that automatically.

Elasticsearch version: 6.2

Comment: I doubt if this is possible. According to my understanding, the reason is, search queries of elastisearch are `stateless` by nature. Which means that every request would be independent and would have nothing to do with other queries hit before and after it. What you are asking, requires, state to be preserved, i.e. have a session, in which you keep track of every request/response until a particular condition is met. I may be wrong but I suppose the only way you can maintain this is from your client end i.e. pro-grammatically as you've mentioned.